# Suddenly started getting warning from virtualenv

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

I am getting the following warning from virtualenv when I start up my environment:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.7.egg\virtualenv.py:446: 
UnicodeWarning: Unicode unequal comparison failed to convert both arguments to 
Unicode - interpreting them as being equal
  if c != content:
Overwriting my_env\Scripts\activate.ps1 with new content
Overwriting my_env\Scripts\activate with new content
Overwriting my_env\Scripts\activate.bat with new content
```

I am 99% positive that nothing changed on my system (Windows 7, x86, Python 2.7.2).  The only thing I should add is that I have not used Python and virtualenv in a while (maybe a year).  But during the elapsed time, there were no Windows updates or service packs applied.

When I look into the Scripts folder under my_env, I see that the three activate* scripts referenced above have new timestamps.  Everything else is the same.

EDIT:

Some additional information:

I removed the three activate* scripts from the Scripts folder.  Then I restarted virtualenv.  No warning.  But the activate* scripts are not re-created, although there is one message that said `Overwriting my_env\Scripts\activate.ps1 with new content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled virtualenv 1.7.1.2, and installed the latest version (1.10.1) using `pip install`.  The problem went away.